# displaying errors in rails app. page 500 on heroku apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am deploying an app on Heroku. Though the experience of deploying is good but I am having pain in fixing stuff.

Very first thing is that `autoincrement` IDs are all messed up between heroku db and my db. So before deploy I have to delete all data from my local app and then push my DB to heroku. If I don't do that then while trying to add a record on heroku app I get duplicate key errors. Is there a way to control autoincrement ids in rails?

Second thing, when there are errors on heroku app. I see the custom 500 error page. `We're sorry, but something went wrong` (500).  Is there a way to show some sort of error message instead? Or I have to depend on heroku logs for that? This is just for development so if some error happens I'd just like to see it on the page itself. Atleast some part of it...

I'm new to Heroku and Rails

Answer (score 6):

autoincrement issue:

maybe using seed data is a better solution for you see http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

errors issue:

in the config/environments/production.rb

try replacing

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = true
config.action_view.cache_template_loading            = true
```

by

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true
config.action_view.debug_rjs                         = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = false
```

cheers

Comment: yeah this did it for me.. thanks it will save me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 1):

You might check the [**Exception Notification**](http://github.com/rails/exception_notification/) plugin to customize how exceptions are handled.

And concerning your db problems, you can [push your local database to herok](http://docs.heroku.com/taps)u using `heroku db:push`

Comment: do I really need a plugin just to show some errors on my 500 page? seems like an overdo. plus the plugin sends emails and stuff. i don't need those feature. i just need bare minimum

Comment: regarding push. i do that. but if some table had id of 5. then on heroku when i add something to that table again. it is giving duplicate key error because autoincrement id is not same there as my local db. i do `heroku db:push` i'm hoping that would take care of autincremented ids and stuff. but apparently not?

Comment: Using a plugin enables you to get the errors by email, without displaying them for the world to see (possibly exposing some internal workings of your app). This is probably a wise thing to do in production.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing the data is one thing, but you might want to look into ways to reset the sequence too. On Heroku they use PGSql, so you'd have to look into its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and editing config/environments/production.rb didn't help. Then I discovered that for some reason, my Heroku app is running in staging mode. I changed the following line in config/environment/staging.rb:

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

to:

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

And now I can see exception traces in my browser!